# How to get content of HashMap's looping on java in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, hashmap

I have this :

```
Map<Integer, String[]> strs = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>(); 
for (int population = 0 ; population < 20 ; population++) {

strs.put(0, morning_food);
strs.put(1, snack1_food);
strs.put(2, lunch_food);
strs.put(3, snack2_food);
strs.put(4, nite_food);

for (String[] value : strs.values()) {
    for (String val : value) {
        Log.d("", val);

    }
}

}
```

this will display the content of strs for 20 times, how can I get first strs, or fourteenth strs or else? I have tried save it to array, but it always display the last strs whatever index I want, any solution? Thx

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Map.put` it will override any value that has already been associated with the key. When you call `Map.put(0, ...)` 20 times, you still only have one value associated with the key `0`, the most recent value passed to `put`.

If you need to store 20 distinct values associated with a single key, use Guava's `Multimap`.

[Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score -1):

use `LinkedHashMap` if you want to loop through it in a set order

Comment: Sure you can, you are just not guaranteed any order